# Takesaki II: lemma 1.2

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra II":

[image]

**Questions**: (1) How does the proof show that every element of $\mathfrak{m}$ is a linear combination of four elements of $\mathfrak{p}?$

I tried to write $x \in \mathfrak{m}$ as $x = (q_1-q_2) + i(q_3-q_4)$ where $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4$ are the canonical positive decomposition of $x$ in $\mathscr{M}$. Somehow we have to argue that $q_i \in \mathfrak{m}$.

(2) Is the factor $1/2$ in the proof correct? I think it should be $1/4$ instead.

(3) Later, Takesaki applies this lemma to a weight $\varphi: \mathscr{M}_+ \to [0, \infty]$ and
$$\mathfrak{p}_\varphi = \{x \in \mathscr{M}: \varphi(x^*x) < \infty\}.$$

Takesaki then mentions that $\varphi$ extends to a linear functional on $\mathfrak{m}_\varphi$ (where this is defined as in the lemma, with respect to our special cone). How exactly is this extension defined?

Comment: There's an error in the definition of $\mathfrak p_\phi$ for the extension of $\phi$. It should be $\mathfrak p_\phi=\{x\in \mathcal M_+\mid \phi(x)<\infty\}$.

Comment: Moreover, results in Takesaki's books are numbered by chapter, so there's probably several Lemmas 1.2. So you should also mention the chapter when refering to his books.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n y_j^*x_j=\tfrac14\,\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^3i^k(x_j+i^ky_j)^*(x_j+i^ky_j)
=\sum_{k=0}^3\tfrac{i^k}4\,\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j+i^ky_j)^*(x_j+i^ky_j)\bigg].
\end{align}
The expression inside the square brackets is in $\mathfrak p$, since $\mathfrak p$ is a subcone.

You are right, it should be $1/4$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k+y_k)^*(x_k+y_k)-(x_k-y_k)^*(x_k-y_k)
&=2\sum_{k=1}^ny_k^*x_k+2\sum_{j=1}^nx_k^*y_k=4a.
\end{align}
And I don't really see why this would be implied by the Polarization Identity.

When you do the above to the sets coming from a weight $\varphi$, you extend to $\mathfrak m$ by using
$$
\varphi\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n y_j^*x_j\Big)
=\sum_{k=0}^3\tfrac{i^k}4\,\varphi\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^n[(x_j+i^ky_j)^*(x_j+i^ky_j)\bigg].
$$
The question is whether the above is well-defined. Suppose we have
$$
a_1-a_2+i(a_3-a_4)=b_1-b_2+i(b_3-b_4)
$$
with $a_j,b_j\in\mathfrak p_\varphi$, $j=1,\ldots,4$. By taking real and imaginary parts,
$$
a_1-a_2=b_1-b_2,\qquad a_3-a_4=b_3-b_4. 
$$
These we can write as
$$
a_1+b_2=b_1+a_2,\qquad a_3+b_4=b_3+a_4.
$$
As $\varphi$ is defined and additive on $p_\varphi$,
$$
\varphi(a_1)+\varphi(b_2)=\varphi(b_1)+\varphi(a_2),\qquad 
\varphi(a_3)+\varphi(b_4)=\varphi(b_3)+\varphi(a_4). 
$$
Thus
$$
\varphi(a_1)-\varphi(a_2)=\varphi(b_1)-\varphi(b_2),\qquad
\varphi(a_3)-\varphi(a_4)=\varphi(b_3)-\varphi(b_4). 
$$
So $\varphi$ has a unique linear extension to $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Thanks! A bit unrelated, but to read the volume II of Takesaki it appears one needs to know a bit about unbounded operators. Would the treatment of Rudin's functional analysis book be enough or do you recommend another reference?

Comment: My knowledge of unbounded operators is *extremely* limited. I don't recall it being an issue when I studied Tomita theory many many years ago. So I would say that most treatments would be enough. If you want a deeper coverage, aimed at operator algebras, you could look at chapter 5 in Kadison Ringrose. But I don't think it's really needed.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks again :)